# How to move functions to another file

Tags: php, wordpress

I developed a query to list fields with checkboxes for the user selection of ones to include in a query result.  It was working in the template file (based on page.php). Then I decided to move the logic that I will be using in other templates to a db-functions.php file. Now, I'm getting

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_results() on null in /home/...

`printf($the_db)` returns the proper login credentials, but apparently an error because `'affected_rows' = -1`.

I can't find what's missing or misconfigured.  Code is below.

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $folder . '/wp-config.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $folder . '/wp-load.php');

//db-setup
function dbsetup($usr, $passwd, $databas, $hst){
    global $wpdb;
    $the_db = new wpdb($usr, $passwd, $databas, $hst);
}

//disp-field-list

function dbfldfrm(){
    $fieldlstress = $the_db->get_results("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns where TABLE_NAME = 'index_records'");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before asking, please search for solution on this site, with the error string. Btw, you need to globalise the variable **from local scope** to be available globally:

```
function dbsetup($usr, $passwd, $databas, $hst){
   global $wpdb;
   global $the_db;
   $the_db = ...
   // same as:   $GLOBALS['the_db'] = ...
```

and secondly, to obtain from global scope, do the same:

```
function dbfldfrm(){

    global $the_db;
    .....
```

Comment: I did search for and found several solutions, none of which worked (I had already tried most of those suggestions).

I did have global @the_db in the file, but must have deleted it in the code sample to simplify the sample.  This is still not working

Comment: @sediger I've updated the answer, it should work now.

Comment: Yes, that did it.  I marked your's as the correct answer.  Thanks T.Todua!